# Single word, noun, the act of increased intensity

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What's one word that means, "the (current/ongoing) act of increasing in intensity"?

I thought Intension had this secondary definition but I can't seem to find any reference.

Comment: It's not much used (I didn't know it, though that may not be saying much! :), but the full OED has  **intension** defn 3 a: *Increase of degree or force; augmentation, **intensification**. (Opp. to **remission**.)*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you, I though I had known this was true! If you put it as the answer I will accept it because it's the one I was looking for.

Comment: I'm a little diffident about that, for two reasons. First, the definition I cited (one of *five* in the full OED) isn't in their ["public access" dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intension?q=Intension), and I prefer not to post answers citing sources not everyone can access. More importantly, OED's last citation for that sense is 1842 - and although they don't actually identify it as "obsolete", I suspect it probably is. But you can copy my comment, post it as an answer yourself, and accept it, if you want. And grab yourself a bit of rep!

Comment: (I upvoted @Paul's ***intensification*** because I think that's the *best* word. But you asked the question, so it's up to you what you accept! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers actually I see your point regarding the public access and citing sources everyone can access readily. I'll put Paul's answer as correct as my question is kind of halfway here, halfway there. The important thing for me here is that I know I had the proper feeling about this word "Intension" so your confirmation that I'm not crazy is good enough for me :-)

Comment: Thinking about it, my first comment prolly wasn't entirely accurate where I said I didn't know the word *intension*. I'm sure I'll have come across it in the *logic* context (as the opposition of *extension*, meaning the *internal content* of a concept). But *in that specific context* the specialised meaning would be obvious every time, so I wouldn't have particularly bothered to make a mental note of it. Bottom line - strictly speaking you *were* right, but idiomatically you want *intensification*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an appropriate answer would be **intensification**.